# getting Deno command line arguments at runtime

Tags: deno

I need to access to deno command line arguments at runtime.

**WAIT**: this is not the question already answered many times. I'm not looking for `Deno.args` that only includes non-deno command line arguments. I need full deno arguments.
For example:

with `deno run --watch main.ts` and `console.log(Deno.args);` I get `[]` whereas I'd like to have something like `['--watch']`

Is it possible?

Comment: CLI `run` arguments are not intended to be accessed by program code. Can you describe your actual use case so we can rule out an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/150810) here? _If you could access them_, why would you want to? (e.g. Is this perhaps related to [denoland/deno#7590](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/7590)?)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75767278/getting-deno-command-line-arguments-at-runtime?noredirect=1#comment134086641_75767278) @rsp I originally downvoted your answer because it was not an answer to the question — but now since you updated it, the answer looks good and I've upvoted it. Still: I suspect it's an XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is it possible?**

**No, it is not possible.** There is no API for that in the Deno namespace:

- https://deno.land/api@v1.32.4?s=Deno

and your script by design cannot get access to anything that is not explicitly exposed in the API.

Also, one might argue that it shouldn't be possible, because it might give access to some data that should not be accessed.

In theory, there might be a new allow flag like `--allow-denoargs` or something like this, but I haven't heard it ever postulated or discussed.

### How it works

The only API to get any runtime arguments is Deno.args, and it currently works like this:

Your own program doesn't get all of the arguments that were passed to the `deno` program. Consider this example of running your program:

```
deno run --watch main.ts a b c
```

The `deno` program will get arguments of:

```js
['run', '--watch', 'main.ts', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

and because it recognizes its `run` command with `--watch` switch option then it will try to find and run your `main.ts` program in watch mode.

But then it will pass only `['a', 'b', 'c']` as the actual arguments to your program - the same as if it were run using:

```
deno run main.ts a b c
```

The `--watch` flag is internal to `deno` and works for `deno run`, `deno test` and `deno fmt` and should't really be detectable for the code that is run that way by default.

### Workarounds

Some possible workarounds:

#### Using environemnt variables

If you really need it for some reason for your code to know in which mode it is running, then you can be creative and use an invocation like this:

```
deno run $WATCH main.ts $WATCH
```

which depending on what is in the WATCH environment variable:

- empty with: `WATCH=`
- set to `--watch` with: `WATCH=--watch`

you will get:

- program run once with nothing `[]` in `Deno.args`
- program run in watch mode with `['--watch']` in `Deno.args`

You can make a shell script to run it more conveniently, or make a Deno task - see:

- https://deno.land/manual@v1.32.4/tools/task_runner

or some other way.

#### Deno tasks

Example with Deno tasks - just for the watch mode:

Having this simple `deno.json` file:

```json
{
  "tasks": {
    "run": "deno run main.ts",
    "watch": "deno run --watch main.ts --watch"
  }
}
```

you can run your program with either:

- `deno task run`
- `deno task watch`

and in the watch mode your program will get the `--watch` flag (or anything that you add there).

#### Universal shell script for all arguments

Using this script, let's call it `denox`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
deno "$@" "$@"
```

you could run your program using:

`denox run --watch main.ts`
instead of:
`deno run --watch main.ts`

and your program will have all of the original `deno` arguments in its `Deno.args`, not just the information about being run in the watch mode or not.

### Summary

The direct answer to "Is it possible?" is unfortunately "No."

**It is possible** to make your code run differently for the watch mode and normal one-off invocation, and **it is** possible to get all of the runtime arguments for `deno`, but **not** using just the Deno APIs. You need to pass that information explicitly by some other way than getting the arguments that are meant for the `deno` program from the Deno runtime (env vars, shell script, Deno tasks, etc.)